# Unexpected Transpile ES6>ES5

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, babeljs, ecmascript-5, transpiler

When transpiling this function into ES5 from ES6 (using Babel) I didn't expect it to change

```
var func = function(msg){
  alert(msg);
}
```

but it became

```
var func = function func(msg) {
        alert(msg);
};
```

Why is this and how does it affect usage of the function, if at all?
Even if it doesn't affect usage, is there anything I should know?
Thank you.

Comment: Is this a question to babel?

Comment: Babel just does what ES6 specifies: All anonymous function expressions assigned to something are getting named.

Comment: If it would affect usage, Babel wouldn't do it.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't affect the usage of the function as well, but it does give the function a way to reference itself.

In the following snippet, notice that I recursively call `ff` -- which is local only to that function, while I invoke it using `func`.

The upshot is:  It's harmless, and you can ignore it.

```js
var func = function ff(t) {
  if (t === 0) {
    console.log("Countdown down");
  } else {
    console.log("Counting down", t);
    ff(t - 1);
  }

};

func(10);
```